# Numbers that share a common power / are powers of the same number

Tags: reference-request, exponentiation, integers

Consider the two following relations on positive integers $n, m > 0$:

- There exist $i, j > 0$ such that $n^i = m^j$
- There exist $x > 0$ and $i, j > 0$ such that $n = x^i$ and $m = x^j$

It is not difficult to show (using the decomposition of $n$ and $m$ into prime factors) that these two relations are equivalent to one another; and also that they are equivalence relations (they are clearly reflexive and symmetric; the interesting point is that they are transitive).

My question: **is there an established name for these relations**, or a name for the fact that they are equivalent? My current terminology is to say that "$n$ and $m$ have a common power" (for the first relation), but if there is an established name I'd rather use it.

(My motivation is from word combinatorics, where similar things are true; but since the question already makes sense for natural numbers I thought I'd ask it in this setting.)

Comment: $i=1$ and $j=1$ must be ruled out to avoid trivial solutions.

Comment: There are other conditions equivalent to the above two for $n,m>1$, such as "The base-$n$ logarithm of $m$ is a rational number" (i.e., $\mathrm{log}_{n}(m) \in \mathbb{Q}$). In the case of $1$, it is "isolated", i.e., no other number is related to $1$.

Comment: @Peter - I don't think so.

Comment: "Numbers that are powers of the same number" may be as close as you get (and even that may need to include a number being understood as a power of itself).  So most people would understand what was meant by "$32$ and $128$ are powers of the same number"